# Broken anchor tag caused by pseudo image background absolute positioning - how to fix?

Tags: css, css-position, anchor, pseudo-element, absolute

I'm struggling to figure out why this anchor tag link won't work when I add a background image to tge pesudo element of the div container.

What's causing the link to break is the 'absolute' positioning of the pseudo element for 'contact-me'. But if I remove that, I lose the image. How do I keep the image and get the anchor tag link to work? Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div id="contact-me">

<h2>Contact</h2>

<h3><a class="btn" href = "mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmail.com</a></h3>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact-me {
  background:      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -webkit- linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -o-linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74     60%, #790c5a 60%);
  color: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;

}

#contact-me:after {
       content: "";
       background: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/cubes.png");
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       right: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       opacity: 0.9;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fffafa;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Any help would be massively apprciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, this:

```
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fffafa;
  z-index: 5;
  position:relative
}
```

Comment: Such a simple fix. I was focusing too much on the z-index - can't believe I didn't think to do this! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you insert `background:      background:` under contact-me ID?
Make your **.btn** class **position: relative;**

Code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    

    #contact-me {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -webkit- linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -o-linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74     60%, #790c5a 60%);
  color: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;

}

#contact-me:after {
       content: "";
       background: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/cubes.png");
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       right: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       opacity: 0.9;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fffafa;
  z-index: 5;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contact-me">

    <h2>Contact</h2>
    
    <h3><a class="btn" href = "mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmail.com</a></h3>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```